# How to deal with reference arguments that may point to internal data?

Tags: c++, reference

More than once I've tracked down a rather baffling bug only to find it was due to a `const` reference parameter changing value part way through a method. This has always been the result of a method receiving a reference argument that happens to refer to (part of) one of its own data members. So when the method mutates that member, the reference (despite being `const`) is mutated as well.

A simple example of what I'm talking about:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class RecentStringBuffer
{
public:
    const std::string & at(size_t index)
    {
        return v.at(index);
    }

    void add(const std::string & s)
    {
        // Remove any previous occurances
        v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), s), v.end());
        // Prepend the new entry
        v.insert(v.begin(), s);
        // Truncate older entries
        v.resize(std::min<size_t>(v.size(), maxEntries));
    }

private:
    const int maxEntries = 10;
    std::vector<std::string> v;
};

int main()
{
    RecentStringBuffer r;
    r.add("A");     // r == [A]
    r.add("B");     // r == [B, A]
    r.add("C");     // r == [C, B, A]
    r.add(r.at(1)); // r == [B, C, A] one would assume?

    std::cout << r.at(0) << r.at(1) << r.at(2); // Prints "A C A"
}
```

In this example, we get a surprising result, but if `v` had reallocated, the reference would have been left pointing outside of `v`'s memory, which would have been much worse. Technically, the reference was invalidated either way, so what ever happens is undefined behaviour.

Similar scenarios can obviously happen with global variables instead of data members and with pointers instead of references, but members and references generally *feel* safer, so this seems like a much more surprising pitfall.

Now, I'm not asking why this happens (I understand what's going on) or how to work around it (there are several obvious ways). My questions are more related to best practices:

- Is there a name for this problem?
- Who is responsible for worrying about this problem?
- Or said another way, where does the bug lie in the above application? When viewed individually, it seems perfectly reasonable and beneficial for `at()` to return a `const` reference and for `add()` to accept one. On the other hand, it doesn't seem all that fair to say that the caller, `main()`, should have known better, either, especially considering that the reference may be passed down through multiple functions before the problem occurs.
- Are there any general strategies for noticing and avoiding such constructs?

Comment: In this concrete example `void add()` takes a *[consume parameter](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-consume)*, i.e. stores it internally, therefore it would be useful to pass it by rvalue reference, or even by value, and then move it to the internal vector. Thus we enforce caller to make a copy if necessary.

Comment: Note that if the getter returned by value then the issue would be moot; `add` would not have to consider the possibility of `s` aliasing `v` because that could never happen.  Having getters return by reference introduces new ways for the code to break. (Not saying never do it, but there are pros and cons).

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov, @M.M As I said, there are lots of ways to workaround the issue in my example, most of them quite trivial. In the real life scenario I encountered yesterday, the container wasn't a `vector`, the argument wasn't a `string` and the reference was passed through two intermediate function calls before being passed back into the offending class. So the fix there wasn't so straightforward, but @M.M's answer still applies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, the implied contract of a function is that it should do what it's supposed to do even if referential arguments refer to something that the function might modify.

If a function doesn't support this then it should be documented clearly.

An example from the standard library is:

- `std::vector::insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last )`  is specifically documented to say "*The behavior is undefined if `first` and `last` are iterators into `*this`*".
- `std::vector::insert( const_iterator pos, const T& value )` has no such documentation, therefore it must work even if `value` refers to an element of the vector. (This was confirmed [by the committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#526)).

So, in your code you either need to modify `add()` to work even if `s` refers to a member of v; or document that it won't work.

Comment: This is a nice, simple answer with a great example. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is ultimately a matter of contracts being violated.

The final problem is that `vector::insert` is called out of contract. It receives a reference as argument that will be invalidated throughout the call ("[...] only the references and iterators *before* the insertion point remain valid", see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)): The insertion point is at the very beginning of the vector, so all iterators and references are invalidated (The call to remove also contributes to the issue but it would remain a problem even if this call did not happen so I'm going to ignore it for simplicitlies sake).

Since the argument to `RecentStringBuffer::add` is passed directly on to `vector::insert` the requirements to the latter's arguments (reference may not be invalidated during `vector::insert`, i.e. not refer to an element inside the container at all) "bleed through" to the former and become part of its contract.

So, to the question at hand:

> Who is responsible for worrying about this problem?

Both the caller and the callee have a responsibility to fulfill:

- The callee must provide the caller with a sufficiently detailed description of the function's contract. If they do not provide any description of a contract, any argument must result in valid behaviour.
- The caller must make sure the contract is fulfilled before the argument is passed to the function. If they fail to do so and call a function out of contract, behaviour is undefined.

This is ultimately exactly what undefined behaviour as a whole is: it's calling code out of contract. For instance, `vector::operator[]` expects its argument to be an index within the container's size. This is well documented and thus it's up to the caller to make sure the given index is not too large. Failing this, the resulting issues are the caller's fault entirely.

In the given example, the author of `RecentStringBuffer::add` should have specified that the argument must not be a reference to an element inside its container. The caller must then determine whether the reference they intend to pass is a legal argument for `RecentStringBuffer::add` and, if necessary, take a copy to pass to the function instead.

The latter is only a problem if a scenario like the one your third bullet point:

> [...] especially considering that the reference may be passed down through multiple functions before the problem occurs.

Though in this scenario, the same principle as described earlier applies: Suppose `RecentStringBuffer::add` is called by a function `foo`, which also receives a `const std::string&` as argument. Since we've already established `RecentStringBuffer::add`'s contract (argument may not refer to one of the elements inside its vector) it's now up to `foo` to make sure the contract holds. If `foo` cannot or should not verify this it must make this requirement part of its contract as well. This principle can be applied recursively up the call chain until at some point some function takes a copy, thus making sure the contract is fulfilled.

Now, designing (and implementing) by contract consistently is difficult and requires a lot of though as well as discipline from the get-go but if it is done properly it can prevent a lot of issues. Such as the one desribed in your question.

Edit: I figured I'd add a consideration for the example given in the question; Propagating the contract up through several layers of a call chain can get annoying and difficult to track. This is one of the reasons picking the correct data structure for a use-case is so important: In the given example, using a container that's more resilient in terms of invalidating references (such as `std::list`; `std::deque` would have also worked since it does not invalidate on inserting to front) would have avoided the issue entirely. Switching to one of these could potentially remove the need for a narrow contract in the given example, but this is not always possible.

Comment: `vector::insert` with single argument has to support that argument being a reference to the vector's member -- the standard says so, and compilers do honour that.  The problem with OP's code comes that he does `erase` and `remove` beforehand, which even if it doesn't invalidate the reference, would make it refer to a different element than intended.

Comment: @M.M I was actually not aware of that. Thanks for pointing it out.